# Date Diff in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, datediff

The Adobe docs point to a function called dateDiff, I cant however see any examples or reference as to what I should be importing to make this function work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation can be found in [com.adobe.fiber.runtime.lib.DateTimeFunc](http://help.adobe.com/de_DE/AS3LCR/Flex_4.0/com/adobe/fiber/runtime/lib/DateTimeFunc.html)

So it should work like this:

```
import com.adobe.fiber.runtime.lib.DateTimeFunc;
```

**But** this package seems not to be a part of the standard Flex SDK, so you better should try [FlexDateUtils](http://code.google.com/p/flexdateutils/).

Answer (score 1):

If you need the code:
http://flexed.wordpress.com/2006/06/26/date-difference/